# Why is it hard to calculate Logarithm on Diffie Hellman?

Tags: key-exchange

i read something about Diffie Hellman. What i don't understand: Alice selects a randomly generated Number, calculates X = g^x mod p and sends X to Bob.

If she calculates g^x, she needs to calcluate g+g+g+g+g... until she has calced to g^x. Than she calculates it mod p and sends the Result to Bob.

If Eve listens, she needs to calculate log_g(X) to find out what to power g to get X, and then calcs it mod n to see if it matches to X.

What is now the difference between the Work Alice has to do (calculating g+g+g+g...) and Eve (calculating g+g+g+g...).

Is the difference that Alice calculates only one Time mod n (after she calculated g^x) and that Eve calculates mod n for every Number she wants to try?

Thank you

Comment: You compute $g^x \bmod p$ via [square-and-multiply](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) in time $(\log(p))^3$, which is feasible for a 1000 bit $p$. The naive algorithms you describe are far too expensive.

Comment: Why $(\log{p})^{3}$? Shouldn't it just be $\log p$?

Comment: @user13741: it's $\log p$ multiplications; however CodesInChaos is estimating that each multiply takes $(\log p)^2$ time (it can be done with better asymptotic time, however the most efficient algorithms in the range we actually use scale at that rate)